# Adding "-" in TextBox.Text

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to add "-" in textBox.Text

I have used textBox.Text.Lines.Length (for get the num of lines in textBox)

I have used .Replace to add "-" but results is null.

Comment: Doesn't `textBox.Text = "-"` work? Or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No where in your post did you say *where* you wanted that dash (or dashes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment on `Alonso Quesada`'s question, it seems that you want to add a `'-'` to the beginning of each line in `textBox`. Here's how to do that:

```
textBox.Lines = (from line in textBox.Lines select "-" + line).ToArray();
```

Basically, this generates an `IEnumerable<string>` containing each line from `textBox.Lines` prefixed by `'-'`, and then sets that back to `textBox.Lines`.

Comment: successful working!
I have solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
TextBox.Lines = TextBox.Lines.Select(l => "-" + l).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the "-" to the end of the Text inside the Textbox?

If so I think textBox.Text += "-" should work

I think I understand know... Then If im correct this should work

```
foreach(string line in textBox.Lines)
{
    line = "- " + line;

}
```

Comment: NO!
for example:
I have written a lot of strings in textBox
In each row add "-" (start, not at end!)
- StackOverflow is a programming site

Answer (score 0):

I cant completely understand your question.
 But you can do this :  textbox.Text = "-"; this way you set the Text property of the control.

If you áre trying to make a custom control you should create a new c# user control, then inheritance from Textbox and make your own methods to do what you want

Comment: i have written a string in textbox, for example:
stackoverflow is a programming site
output:
- stackoverflow is a programming site

Comment: Do you want to delete the final '-' character?